# Foco sempre no JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Eu preciso que quando eu clicar em algum botão da minha aplicação o foco retorne para o `JFrame`. Existe algum método para isso?

Eu poderia chamar o método `MeuFrame.requestFocus()` em cada `ActionPerformed`, mas isso demoraria muito.

Answer (score 1):

Existe sim, tente:

Você diz pro seu `jButton` transferir o foco e pede pro seu `jFrame` solicitar esse foco.

```
 jButton.transferFocus();
 jFrame.requestFocus();
```

Você ainda pode obter o foco forçando através do:

```
jFrame.grabFocus();
```

Esse método obtém o foco independente de quem o tiver (força a transferência do foco pra si), inclusive trás o foco para a janela caso ela não esteja ativa.

Eu lhe recomendaria utilizar da primeira forma, porque o efeito do segundo pode ser indesejado ao usuário.

Comment: existem muitos botões na minha aplicação... Demoraria muito...

Comment: não tem outro jeito não?

Comment: cada botão seu deve dizer que deve transferir

Comment: @Dongabi seus botões não têm uma ação? É só colocar no fim da ação.